# How to fix ImportError: No module named comments.models when it exists in INSTALLED_APPS as 'apps.comments'?

Tags: python, django-models, deployment, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to update my site and ran into this issue when I ran 'python manage.py makemigrations' after I had 'git pull origin master' of my updated project onto ubuntu.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/python-portfolio/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/python-portfolio/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ubuntu/python-portfolio/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ubuntu/python-portfolio/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/ubuntu/python-portfolio/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
    **import**(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/python-portfolio/apps/blog/models.py", line 11, in 
    from apps.comments.models import Comment

ImportError: No module named comments.models

However, this app is created and is stored as 'apps.comments', in INSTALLED_APPS.

I am not sure how to go about it because on localhost it works fine and I did not have an ImportError issue. The comment app is a new model prior to the update.

### blog/models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.text import slugify

from markdown_deux import markdown
from apps.comments.models import Comment
```

### comments/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CommentManager()
```

### settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # LOCAL APPS
    'apps.accounts',
    'apps.blog',
    'apps.work',
    'apps.comments',
    # DJANGO APPS
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # THIRD PARTY APPS
    'crispy_forms',
    'pagedown',
    'markdown_deux',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

I am hoping I can run migrations, migrate and collectstatic to update my site. I appreciate the community's help.

## Update

I had tried to comment the line out and run migrations to see what happens but I would face similar ImportError issues with other parts of the app such as ImportError: No module named comments.forms.

## Fixed

Instead of setting it like this:

```
from apps.comments.models import Comment
```

Pointing it to the relative path worked:

```
from ..comments.models import Comment
```

Comment: since I suspect sys.path differences, could you **import sys** then **[print(pth) for pth in sys.path]**. compare between where it works and doesn't work?  You could put those 2 lines right above the failing import in blog/models.py

Comment: I added those lines to see the paths listed but I don't know what comparison I am supposed to make. It has listed paths from my local environment and paths from the ubuntu environment where I am trying to make the changes to get it live.

Comment: I am going to try to move my apps.comments from INSTALLED_APPS above apps.blog to see if that makes a difference. Maybe it needs to recognize the comments model first before it can pull it from apps.blog?

Comment: My attempt did not do anything.

Comment: what happens if you just add `apps.blog` and `import apps.comments` before the INSTALLED_APPS?  does a normal import work?  does `apps.blog` work, but not `apps.comments`.  Yes, you may have a circular import issue, but that would generally be the case on all environments, which is why I think the problem is more likely to be with your `sys.path`.  basically, one of your `sys.path` entries needs to have a subdirectory `apps` that has your installed stuff in it.  once you find it where it works, see if it's missing on the machine where it doesn't.

Comment: They both work in localhost. I figured another way to go around it and changed the line to from ..comments.models import Comment. And made these adjustments to other parts of my app. It seemed to work. Although I when I made my updates and restarted gunicorn and nginx, I have a 500 internal server error...

Comment: I appreciate your help JL Peryret!